# What is coordinate matrix $[1_v]_{xy}$? And how can I show it is equivalent to composition of matrix and its inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inverse

I am trying to solve the following problem from the previous year's exams of my Linear Algebra 1 (using FDLA by M. Gockenbach textbook):

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional nontrivial vector spaces over F with $dim(V)=n$ and $dim(W)=m$. Let $X$, $Y$ be bases for $V$ and $Z$, $S$ bases for $W$. Let $E_B$ be coordinate maps defined by $E_B(v)=[v]_B$ for each basis.
Show that $(E_Y○E^{-1}_X)(x) = [1_v]_{X,Y}(x)$ for any $x\in F^n$

If I understand correctly $E_B$ are matrices that map vector $v$ into a vector with respect to a certain basis. I think that by composition rules, the left hand side becomes $E^{-1}_X(E_Y(x))$ and, by multiplication by its own inverse we get identity matrix. So if I am correct, does $[1_v]_{X,Y}$ represent change of coordinate matrix where the $1$ represents identity?

I am not sure if my proof would be sufficient. Are there any key points that are missing in it?

Comment: It should be $(E_Y \circ E_X^{-1})(x) = E_Y(E_X^{-1}(x))$ (unless a strange convention is being used here, which I doubt). $1_v$ seems to be the identity function on $V,$ I personally would write it as $1_V$ or even better $I_V.$ Other than that, to _prove_ the identity, you need to state what definition you are working on. In plain English, $E_X^{-1}(x)$ is the vector $v \in V$ whose coordinates under $X$ are $x,$ and $E_Y(v)$ are the coordinates of $v$ in the basis $Y.$ What definition do you use for $[1_v]_{X,Y}$?

Comment: Actually, that's what I am confused about. We have defined $I_n = [1_v]_{X,X}$ in the class. So I think that $[1_v]_{X,Y}$ is some change of coordinates matrix that changes a linear operator from Y to X? i.e. $[1_w]_{Z,S} [E]_{Y,S} = [E]_{X,Z} [1_v]_{Y,X}$. Does that make sense? @WilliamM.

Comment: There are a few issues that emerge, for example, if you have defined $I = [1_v]_{X,X},$ you should have checked this definition does not depend on the choice of basis (or of vector space!). I would assume that $E_YE_X^{-1}$ _is the definition_ of the change of basis transformation.